# Does HTTP not support providing a checksum in a form of header for downloaded content?

Tags: http, download

Is there a way to tell a browser downloading a file or page that the content it is downloading should match this checksum made with this formula (e.g. sha-1 or md5)?

I think it would be great to verify file integrity without having to manually verify the file's integrity after download.

If it is possible, how would I implement this in my own server? If not, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Digest` is the standard header used to convey the checksum of a selected representation of a resource (that is, the payload body).

An example response with digest.

```
>200 OK
>...
>Digest: sha-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=
>
>{"hello": "world"}
```

`Digest` may be used both in request and responses.
It's a good practice to validate the data against the digest before processing it.

You can see the [related page on mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Digest) for an indepth discussion around the payload body in http.

> I guess that whole HTTP-based Internet is working, because we're using TCP protocol

No, the integrity on the web is ensured by TLS. Non-TLS communication should not
be trusted. See [rfc8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-1)

---

Source: [Roberto Polli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473111/roberto-polli)'s answer to [Checksum in HTTP response header - why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640318/checksum-in-http-response-header-why-not)